# I can't seem to get overflow:"hidden" to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to disable scrolling beyond the monitor resolution by hiding overflow. I am not sure why it is not working.

App.js file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App"
    style={{
      overflow:"hidden"
      }}
    >
    <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        component={DefaultView}

    ></Route>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Default View File:

```
render(){
        return(
            <div
                style={{
                    overflow:"hidden"
                }}>
                <div
                    className="bg"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor:"#FFFFF",
                        position:"absolute",
                        width:"100%",
                        height:"100%"
                        }}
                />
                <div 
                    className="line"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor:"#289BD3",
                        position:"absolute",
                        height:"1000px",
                        width:"1920px",
                        transform:"rotate(45deg)",
                        top:"200px",
                        left:"-800px"
                    }}
                >
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Right now, there is no X scrolling, but I can scroll up and down.

A codesandbox of the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rylyo4zy24

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you asking about the CSS?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `overflow: hidden` element that is scolling?  You want `overflow:hidden` to be on the container element...maybe you just need to apply that style to your <body>?

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) or another site showing how the code is not working.

Comment: If you use overflow: hidden property then parent component should be positioned absolute and child component should positioned relative

Answer (score 2):

I changed the parent div's position to absolute and my child div's positions to relative, solving the issue.

Comment: Well, that's just plain wrong. `overflow: hidden` does not require absolute positioning.

Comment: I would suggest rewriting the answer to be less prescriptive (for instance "I positioned the parent absolute and the child relative and it fixed the issue" with the code used).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish here, but for overflow hidden to have any meaning you need to define some height and/or width for the respective element:

```
<div
  style={{
    overflow:"hidden",
    height:"1000px",
    width:"1920px"
  }}
>
...
```